# <a href='%%=RedirectTo(@url)=%%'>Link</a> is not rendering correctly for non-English emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, language

First time encountering this issue! Super weird. So, it seems that when I do a simple

```
<a href='%%=RedirectTo(@url)=%%'>click here</a>
```

The resulting URL is fine when the email is English.
[image]

But, when the email is any other language, here's what I get. See the URL that is prepended before the "kytracing.link" URL? This only happens for non-English emails. Any ideas why this might be happening? As you can expect, clicking the erroneous email results in a 404 Not Found error.

[image]

Comment: The domain you want to redirect is "kytracing.link" (take the contact to "http://kytracing.link/mcgg")?

Comment: No it's kytracing.link/mcgg is the domain it should direct to

Answer (score 0):

If the protocol and domain doesn't change (It's the same for every record in your DE). You can use just the endpoint as variable in your DE.

> Personalization strings with attributes can be used when the protocol
> and domain are included in the href value in the static message
> content.

[Dynamic Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_link_tracking.htm&type=5)

So you can change your `<a>` tag to

```
<a href='https://kytracing.link/%%RebrandedUrl%%'>click here</a>
```

And in your DE you should change the values from the `RebrandedUrl` field to contain just the string after the `/`

`kytracing.link/mcgg` -> `mcgg`